# Django query ~ Raw query must include the primary key

Tags: python, django, django-models

I try to make raw query in django but error

> Raw query must include the primary key

this is query:

```
posts= User.objects.raw('select auth_group.name, auth_user.username 
                        from auth_user, auth_group, auth_user_groups 
                        where auth_user.id = auth_user_groups.user_id AND auth_group.id = auth_user_groups.group_id')
```

can you help me?

Comment: please look at this for writing raw sql query: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/

Comment: thanks I try to use raw sql but show eror like i edit above. how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is a shell example. This may give a hint. 
`User` and `Group` are in `many-to-many` relationship.

```
In [24]: from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

In [25]: user_id = 9038

In [26]: u = User.objects.get(id=user_id)

In [27]: u.username
Out[27]: u'parag@gmail.com'

In [28]: g = Group.objects.filter(user=u)

In [29]: g.all()
Out[29]: [<Group: Customer>, <Group: Admin>, <Group: Author>, <Group: Tester>, <Group: Report>]
```